# htm5 audio is not working on safari when I use jquery's timeout

Tags: html, safari

I can play a song right after 5 seconds in my chrome browser but it doesn't work in safari. when I click on button text directly, it plays fine in safari too.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function playAudio(){

       var a=new Audio("on.mp3");
         a.load();
         a.play();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

      setTimeout(function() {
         playAudio();

      }, 5000);


});

</script>


</head>
<body>

Audio will start playing after 5 second
<p  id="playButton" onclick="playAudio()">button</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because of Safari auto-play policy that require a user gesture to play media : https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos

Comment: that happened in chrome as well so that's related to IOS policy i guess